Next JS production problem with Highlight,js(Can't use code highlight)
I am trying to implement the Highlight.js with my Next.js website's blog page which is dynamically fetches data. All seems fine until I push it to production. In production it gives me client side error like :
"Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)."
I can't find a way how to fix it.
Images : https://imgur.com/a/W7FkxKg
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Blogs from "../../models/blogs";
import Head from "next/head";
import Comments from "@/components/commments";
import hljs from "highlight.js";
import "highlight.js/styles/atom-one-dark.css"; // You can choose any other style from highlight.js styles

const Blog = ({ blogs }) => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState(true);
  const [isHljsApplied, setisHljsApplied] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
    setMode(darkMode === "true");
    const codeBlocks = document.querySelectorAll("pre");
    codeBlocks.forEach((codeBlock) => {
      if (!codeBlock.parentNode.classList.contains("code-wrapper")) {
        hljs.highlightElement(codeBlock);
        const preWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        preWrapper.className = "code-wrapper relative";
        codeBlock.parentNode.insertBefore(preWrapper, codeBlock);
        preWrapper.appendChild(codeBlock);
        const copyButton = document.createElement("i");
        copyButton.className =
          "bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 transition duration-300 px-2 py-1 cursor-pointer rounded-md text-gray-600 copy-button absolute top-0 right-0 m-2 bx bx-copy";
        copyButton.onclick = () =>
          handleCopy(codeBlock.textContent.trim(), copyButton);
        copyButton.textContent = "";
        preWrapper.appendChild(copyButton);
      }
    });
    // Add CSS class to paragraphs containing images
    // const blogContent = document.querySelector(".ql-editor.blog");
    // if (blogContent) {
    //   const paragraphs = blogContent.querySelectorAll("p");
    //   paragraphs.forEach((paragraph) => {
    //     if (paragraph.querySelector("img")) {
    //       paragraph.classList.add("flex", "justify-center");
    //     }
    //   });
    // }
  }, []);
  const handleCopy = (code, copyButton) => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(code).then(() => {
      copyButton.classList.remove("bx-copy");
      copyButton.textContent = "Copied!";
      setTimeout(() => {
        copyButton.textContent = "";
        copyButton.classList.add("bx-copy");
      }, 1000);
    });
  };
  
  
  
  


  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{blogs.title} | Soubhagyajit</title>
        <script
          async
          src="https://www.won't_tell_you.com"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <link rel="canonical" href={`https://www.soubhagyajit.com/blogs/${blogs.slug}`} />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content={`${blogs.content.substring(3, 500)} . . .`}
        />
      </Head>
      {/* {!isHljsApplied && (<><div className="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-50 backdrop-blur-2xl">
      <div className="bg-white p-4 rounded-lg">
        <h2 className="text-xl text-red-500 mb-4 text-center">Caution!</h2>
        
        <div className="flex justify-end text-center">
          Something is blocked by your browser.<br/>Try disabling your adblocker.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></>)} */}
      <main className={mode ? 'dark' : ''}>
        <div className="pt-20 transition-all dark:bg-slate-900">
          <div className="ml-[2%] sm:p-10 p-5 sm:mx-[5%] md:mx-[15%] lg:mx-[30%] sm:py-5 transition-all dark:text-white">
            <h1 className="sm:text-5xl text-3xl font-bold">{blogs.title}</h1>
            <p className="text-gray-500 my-5 text-[16px]">
              <span className="flex items-center">
                <div className="border-2 border-blue-600 w-fit rounded-full mr-2">
                  <img
                    className="object-cover rounded-full "
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/h1huc0w.png"
                    alt="Soubhagyajit Borah"
                    width={50}
                  />
                </div>
                <span className="flex flex-col items-center">
                  Soubhagyajit Borah
                  <span className="text-gray-500 text-[16px]">
                    {new Date(blogs.createdAt).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
                      year: "numeric",
                      month: "long",
                      day: "numeric",
                    })}
                  </span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </p>
            <hr className="border-none bg-slate-500 h-[1px] my-6" />
            <div className="my-4 text-lg">
              <div
                className="blog"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: blogs.content }}
              ></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Comments blogs={blogs} />
          <style>
            {`h1{
                font-size:2rem;
              }
              h2{
                font-size:1.5rem;
              }
              h3{
                font-size:1.17rem;
              }
              .blog{
                padding:0;
              }
              pre{
                max-height:50vh;
                border-radius: 3px;
                background-color: #23241f;
                overflow: auto;
              }
              pre.ql-syntax {
                margin: 2px 0;
                padding: 10px;
              }
              .blog a{
                color:blue !important;
                text-decoration: underline !important;
              }
              blockquote em{
                margin: 0 10px;
              }
              blockquote {
                font-size: 1.25em;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 64px auto;
                font-family: Open Sans;
                font-style: italic;
                color: #555555;
                padding: 1.2em 30px 1.2em 75px;
                border-left: 6px solid lightgray;
                line-height: 1.6;
                position: relative;
                background: ghostwhite;
                border-radius: 4px;             
              }
              .image-paragraph img {
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
              }
              @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
                .blog a {
                  color: #58b1ff;
                }
              }
            `}
          </style>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  if (!mongoose.connections[0].readyState) {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
  }
  const { slug } = context.query;

  let blogs = null;
  try {
    blogs = await Blogs.findOne({ slug: slug });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching blog data:", error);
  }

  return {
    props: { blogs: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blogs)) },
  };
}

export default Blog;

I tried everything from placing console logs on some places, tried other libraries like Prism and react-syntax-highlight. Also tried to render the highlight function after proper loading of the page.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
